# Learning rate: Normalised Leat Mean Squares

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, least-squares

I was wondering why when performing NLMS regression the learning rate $\eta>0$ for the following update rule:

$$w_t=w_{t-1}-\frac{\eta}{1+\eta||x_t||_2^2}(x_t'w_{t-1}-y_t)x_t$$

If I set $\eta<0$ will I be violating any mathematical conditions?